# Java Errors From an Excel API

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I do hope someone can help me or point me to someone who can, with this problem.
I have been working with someone who wanted to extend the capabilities of an Excel Spreadsheet that is embedded in a Third Party application that provides streamed stock market data via a Java interface. The user is allowed to interact with the spreadsheet, so we built some analysis and a graph into it, and everything generally works OK, but we get frequent situations where the whole system will crash and an extensive error log is produced.

As we don't know Java, we are unable to understand the log very well. We did notice that the logs all seem to be reporting this error:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)
```

and the stack detail shows entries for `JExcel` and `jniwrapper`.

To try to establish whats causing this, we desperately need someone who can
decipher these logs. We have tried contacting the providers but its a large organization and they haven't suggested anything helpful.

We have put a lot of work into the spreadsheet, and we are now completely derailed by this problem. Please can anyone help us?

Comment: It sounds like some native library being used is crashing. So, the first question would be: what JVM version are you using, and what native library is causing the problem.  
Just below that message, does it say, Function=ABCDEFG,  Library= C:\WINNT\XYZXYZ.DLL ?